# Avoid conditional counter increment in Python loop

Tags: python

How can I avoid having to increment the `count_odd_values` variable manually in the following Python code:

```
count_odd_values = 0
for value in random.sample(range(1000), 250):
  if value % 2 == 1:
    count_odd_values += 1
```

Comment: @Josh Thanks, but I don't see how. I am new to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
count_odd_values = sum(value % 2 for value in random.sample(range(1000), 250))
```

All the even numbers will give `value % 2 == 0` and will not change the sum.
All the odd numbers will give `value % 2 == 1` and sum will be incremented by 1.

Comment: thanks, i assume this would generalize to a condition that checks a database object in django?

Comment: Sorry, can't say much for Django, not experienced. All I know is that this code will count odd numbers in "whatever's provided by `random.sample(...)`"

Comment: Less useless addition would be required with `sum(1 for value in random.sample(range(1000), 250) if value % 2)`.